# copy over rows a specific number of times based on column value in R

Tags: r

Hey guys I have a data frame in R which looks something like the following

| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | J | Jon |
| Amy | K | White |
| Ravi | M | Khanna |

I want to add a column for year and repeat the rows with the number of years, something like

| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | J | Jon | 2020 |
| Jim | J | Jon | 2021 |
| Jim | J | Jon | 2022 |
| Amy | K | White | 2020 |
| Amy | K | White | 2021 |
| Amy | K | White | 2022 |
| Ravi | M | Khanna | 2020 |
| Ravi | M | Khanna | 2021 |
| Ravi | M | Khanna | 2022 |

Does anyone have any advice on how I can go about doing this in R? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Year = list(2020:2022)) %>%
  unnest(Year)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  FirstName MiddleName LastName  Year
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>    <int>
1 Jim       J          Jon       2020
2 Jim       J          Jon       2021
3 Jim       J          Jon       2022
4 Amy       K          White     2020
5 Amy       K          White     2021
6 Amy       K          White     2022
7 Ravi      M          Khanna    2020
8 Ravi      M          Khanna    2021
9 Ravi      M          Khanna    2022
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base `R`

```
lapply(df , \(x) rep(x , rep(3,3))) |> data.frame() |>
(\(x) `[[<-`(x ,"Year", value = 2020:2022))()
```

- output

```
  FirstName MiddleName LastName Year
1       Jim          J      Jon 2020
2       Jim          J      Jon 2021
3       Jim          J      Jon 2022
4       Amy          K    White 2020
5       Amy          K    White 2021
6       Amy          K    White 2022
7      Ravi          M   Khanna 2020
8      Ravi          M   Khanna 2021
9      Ravi          M   Khanna 2022
```

- data

```
df <- structure(list(FirstName = c("Jim", "Amy", "Ravi"), MiddleName = c("J", 
"K", "M"), LastName = c("Jon", "White", "Khanna")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```